# How to convert RGB values from .txt file to display an image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, rgb, face-detection

I have a .txt file which contains RGB values, when I open and read the files, the pixel values are in str format. How do I convert these values to display an image in python. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qftw1.png).

This is the [image: value gotten] when I tried reading the values. They are all in a string format.

Edit: You can find the link for the file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mAxlcMj_SVeK0axJhbPJqO4k_egJoYli/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include your actual data for folks to work with rather than pictures of data.  Thank you. https://xkcd.com/2116/ If it's too big for StackOverflow, maybe use Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Some of your RGB values are not separated by commas, can you further explain this? Each pixel would need to have three values hence RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick quite simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

# Open image file, slurp the lot
contents = Path('image.txt').read_text()

# Make a list of anything that looks like numbers using a regex...
# ... taking first as height, second as width and remainder as pixels
h, w, *pixels = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', contents)

# Now make pixels into Numpy array of uint8 and reshape to correct height, width and depth
na = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((int(h),int(w),3))

# Now make the Numpy array into a PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save("result.png")
```

[image]

---

If you want to write the output image with **OpenCV** instead of with **PIL/Pillow**, change the last line above to the following so it does RGB->BGR reordering and uses `cv2.imwrite()` instead:

```
# Save with OpenCV instead
cv2.imwrite('result.png', na[...,::-1])
```

---

If you want to write a PPM file (compatible with **Photoshop**, **GIMP**, **OpenCV**, **PIL/Pillow** and **ImageMagick**), *without* using **PIL/Pillow** or **OpenCV** or any extra libraries, and have it around 1/4 the size of your original file, you can write it very simply in binary by replacing the last line above with:

```
# Save "na" as binary PPM image
with open('result.ppm','wb') as f:
   f.write(f'P6\n{w} {h}\n255\n'.encode())
   f.write(na.tobytes())
```

---

In fact, you don't need any Python, you can do it directly at the command line in Terminal if you write a [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) file that can be read by **Photoshop**, **GIMP**, **PIL/Pillow**

```
awk 'NR==1{$0="P3\n" $2 " " $1 "\n255"} {gsub(/,/,"\n")} 1' image.txt > result.ppm
```

That script basically *"massages"* your first line so it goes from this:

```
418 870
... rest of your data ...
```

to this:

```
P3
870 418
255
... rest of your data ...
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot Mark

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project. Come back if you get stuck and ask another question - they are free, as are answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It  is necessary to identify two steps to solve this problem:

**1. Parse the file** to get the pixels  and the image's width and height. In this step, you need to know how information was
stored in the file.

**2.  Use OpenCV to show the image**. Below is a basic example to show a matrix as an image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# image of 100 x 100 pixels , with 3 channels 
height=100 
width=100
channels=3 
color_bg=(0,0,0) 
imgdim = (height, width, channels ) 
blank_image = np.full(imgdim, color_bg, np.uint8)
#Simple way to change the pixel(x=1,y=2) color to the (B=255,G=0,R=0) tuple color 
blank_image[1,2]= (255,0,0) 

cv2.imshow("blank", blank_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please read the doc of [Basics operations with opencv-python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) to understand the concepts and performance recomendations about numpy.

Comment: This is well explained. However, when I tried to read in t values from the txt file, they were all strings, which would mean I would have to change  the type of all the numbers from a str to int type. This is so unproductive. I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this. Thank you. Also, my image is 418, 870

Answer (score 0):

Well to read a txt file you need this code

```
file= open("filename.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
```

then you can get the numbers in each line with the function

```
lines[0].split(",")
```

finally you can use pillow to make the [image with the data](https://code-maven.com/create-images-with-python-pil-pillow)

```
    from PIL import Image
     
    img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')
    img.save('pil_red.png')
```

Comment: You still need to clean your data and make sense of each line by yourself

Comment: Where do you use the data?